# How to change function name in the display of a pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

I am making a machine learning model on the titanic dataset. Click [here](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic/data) to access the data.

For starters, I started off by creating a pivot table to understand the differences in Central Tendencies for people who survived the disaster, and for the people who didn't.

I use the code below to get the `pivot_table`.

```
pd.pivot_table(
    data = train_df, 
    values = ["Pclass", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare", "Cabin", "Embarked"], 
    index = "Survived", 
    aggfunc = ["mean", "median", lambda series:series.mode()[0]]
    )
```

Output -

[image]

Because I can't just pass in "mode" in the `aggfunc` parameter like I can pass "mean", I made a lambda function to do the job. But because of it "< lambda >" shows up in the pivot table. How can I change it to display something like "mode"?

I can definitely create a function by the name `mode` but is there some other way?

Comment: lambdas are supposed to be _anonymous_ functions. Try defining a normal function with `def mode` (not 100% sure it will work though)

Comment: @matszwecja That would work but again, it would lengthen up the code by a bit for pure aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not sure, but by reading the documentation I think that since you can use a lambda function, you could also create a function and set a name for it.

Answer (score 0):

I get your desired behavior by using the class method directly:

```py
import pandas
import seaborn

df = seaborn.load_dataset("titanic")

pandas.pivot_table(
    data=df, 
    values=["pclass", "age", "sibsp"], 
    index="survived", 
    aggfunc=[
        "median",
        pandas.Series.mode # <-- no lambda
    ]
)
```

The result:

```
         median               mode             
            age pclass sibsp   age pclass sibsp
survived                                       
0          28.0      3     0  21.0      3     0
1          28.0      2     0  24.0      1     0
```

This implies that you can define any function and it's `__name__` attribute will be used.

Comment: I tried `pd.Series.mode` and got this error `ValueError: Must produce aggregated value`.

Comment: @Zero That’s the error you got when you copy/pasted my code and ran it?

Comment: No, I just changed the lambda function with `pd.Series.mode`.